# Reading a null terminated string from a binary file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

As the title says I'm trying to read a null terminated string from a binary file.

```
std::string ObjElement::ReadStringFromStream(std::ifstream &stream) {
    std::string result = "";
    char ch;
    while (stream.get(ch) != '\0') {
        result += ch;
    }
    return result; }
```

My null character is '\0'

But any time I call the method it reads to the end of the file

```
std::ifstream myFile(file, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
myFile.seekg(startByte);

this->name = ObjElement::ReadStringFromStream(myFile);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to provide ios::in or set empty string to "" explicitly.

Comment: `stream.get(ch)` doesn't return the character.

Comment: im not reading from the start of the file, I have the start byte I need from somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure the file contains the ASCII Zero character in it? How did you get/create the file?

Comment: Ooops my bad about the start byte. Need moar coffee

Comment: Suggestion:  Change the parameter to `std::istream & stream`  That would make unit testing easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`istream::get(char &)` returns a reference to the `istream`, not the character read. You can either use the `istream::get()` variant like so:

```
while ((ch = stream.get()) != '\0') {
    result += ch;
}
```

Or use the returned stream reference as a `bool`:

```
while (stream.get(ch)) {
    if (ch != '\0') {
        result += ch;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::getline`:

```
#include <string> // for std::getline

std::string ObjElement::ReadStringFromStream(std::ifstream &stream) {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(stream, s, '\0');
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: This comment gives a straightforward implementation of the question in the title, but it does not answer the 'Why does my code fail question'  related to the body of the question. Answering the title helped me most.

Answer (score 4):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and pass `\0` (null character) as the delimiter.

Comment: Could the downvoter explicitly explain why this wouldn't work?

Comment: yeah, this is easier than my way of doing it. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` function returns a reference to the stream , not the character which has been put in `ch`
.

You need to test `ch` for being a '\0'.

Comment: ahhhh I see what I've done. Thats probably it alright

Answer (score 0):

The get function returns the reference of the stream not the read character.

Modifiy the code like:

```
std::string ObjElement::ReadStringFromStream(std::ifstream &stream) {
    std::string result = "";
    while (stream.get(ch)) { // exit at EOF
        if (ch != '\0')
            result += ch;
        else
            break;  // Stop the loop when found a '\0'
    }
    return result; 
}
```